# getting annotation based bean using BeanfactoryAware

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am using spring 3.x for my application. I used annotations to configure spring beans,
but in some scenarios i need to get object of a bean by its name. In XML based configuration i could do this by implementing `BeanfactoryAware` and calling `getbean("beanName")`. Is this possible in annotation based spring configuration. If so how can i use it, since I am not much aware of annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use parameter of annotation

1. `@Bean(name = "beanName")`
2. `@Service(value = "beanName")`

   If not specify *value* then Spring create bean with name of Java Naming Conventions:

   `@Service
   class ExampleBean { }`
   in this case we have bean with name *exampleBean*.

And then

```
    getBean("beanName") getBean("exampleBean")
```

Comment: I used @Named annotation.Then

Comment: ie, the required bean is not declared in @Configuration annotated class.